# Mostrar mes SQL

Tags: sql

Estimad@s, buenos días, tengo una duda sencilla pero que no estoy viendo. Tengo una consulta que se encarga de mostrar el año y el mes. Este último se muestra cuando el año es superior a 0. El inconveniente que tengo es que deseo mostrar el nombre del mes pero no veo mi error. Mi error:

```
Error de conversión al convertir el valor varchar 'Enero' al tipo de datos int.
```

****Quiero aclarar que en mi tabla, tanto Ano como Mes son campos de tipo INT**

Mi consulta:

```
DECLARE @ano integer
set @ano = 2024

SELECT DISTINCT 
                (CASE WHEN @ano = 0 THEN
                         Ano
                    ELSE
                         Mes --mi problema está aquí, si lo dejo así funciona 
                         --DATENAME(MONTH, Mes) pero al ponerlo así sale el error mencionado
                END)
        FROM            
                VigenciaTablaValores 
        WHERE   
            activo = 0
            AND (@ano = 0 
                OR Ano = @ano)
```

Imágenes descriptivas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ah.. es que el problema es que la columna no puede ser al mismo tiempo int (si el año es 0) o varchar.. o es una cosa, o la otra... y si convertis el año a varchar tambien????

Comment: Así que ese era el error que no estaba vieno, muchísimas gracias! @gbianchi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que la expresión `CASE` utiliza la prioridad de los tipos de datos para definir el tipo de dato que regresará. En este caso, el tipo int tiene una mayor prioridad que varchar (que es lo que regresa DATENAME). Por lo mismo, tienes que asegurarte de que todos los datos que regreses tengan un tipo de dato de cadena.

Otro detalle es el que quieres usar funciones de fecha sobre enteros y aunque no genera un error, sí obtendrás resultados incorrectos porque los enteros se convierten a fecha y generan una fecha distinta. Te incluyo código con 2 posibles soluciones, una de ellas está comentada.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                (CASE WHEN @ano = 0 THEN
                         CAST( Ano AS varchar(15))
                    ELSE
                         --DATENAME( MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, Mes - 1, 0))
                         CASE Mes
                            WHEN 1  THEN 'Enero'
                            WHEN 2  THEN 'Febrero'
                            WHEN 3  THEN 'Marzo'
                            WHEN 4  THEN 'Abril'
                            WHEN 5  THEN 'Mayo'
                            WHEN 6  THEN 'Junio'
                            WHEN 7  THEN 'Julio'
                            WHEN 8  THEN 'Agosto'
                            WHEN 9  THEN 'Septiembre'
                            WHEN 10 THEN 'Octubre'
                            WHEN 11 THEN 'Noviembre'
                            WHEN 12 THEN 'Diciembre'
                        END
                END)
        FROM            
                VigenciaTablaValores 
        WHERE   activo = 0
            AND (@ano = 0 
                OR Ano = @ano)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entonces convierte primero el ano y mes en una fecha y luego utiliza la DATENAME()

La funcion de DATENAME() te imprimira el nombre del mes de lo que desees pero lo que tiene que ir dentro tiene que ser una fecha!

Consulta:

```
DECLARE @ano integer
set @ano = 2024

SELECT DISTINCT 
    (CASE WHEN @ano = 0 THEN
        Ano
    ELSE
        DATENAME(MONTH, DATEFROMPARTS(@ano, Mes, 1))
    END)
FROM            
    VigenciaTablaValores 
WHERE   
    activo = 0
    AND (@ano = 0 
        OR Ano = @ano)
```

Comment: Tampoco funciona

Comment: Si dices que ano es int y mes también es un int, esto funciona! DATENAME(month, DATEFROMPARTS(2014, 1, 1))

Comment: Te digo que no funciona, observa la pregunta, he adjuntado imágenes usando tu respuesta y del formato de la tabla!

Comment: fijate mi comentario.. la columna es numeros y texto segun lo que ingresa, al mismo tiempo1!!!!!}